# C++ Instantiate Template Variadic Class

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class P>
void processAll() {
    P p = P();
    p.process();
}

class P1 {
public:
    void process() { std::cout << "process1" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    processAll<P1>();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to inject a second class 'P2' into my function 'processAll', using template variadic ? Something like this :

```
...

template<class... Ps>
void processAll() {
    // for each class, instantiate the class and execute the process method
}

...

class P2 {
public:
    void process() { std::cout << "process2" << std::endl; }
};

...

int main() {
    processAll<P1, P2>();
    return 0;
}
```

Can we iterate over each class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) (c++17), you might do:

```
template<class... Ps>
void processAll()
{
    (Ps{}.process(), ...);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using C++17's fold expressions you may forward execution of several processes to the common "process single `P`" implementation:

```
template<typename P>
void processSingle() {
    P p = P();
    p.process();
}

template<typename... Ps>
void processAll() {
    (processSingle<Ps>(), ...);
}
```

If the logic of `processSingle()` is simple you could skip implementing it in a separate function and instead place all of it within the fold expression, as shown in @Jarod42's answer.

Comment: could you please correct the following statement _you skip could implement the it within_. Thanks